# Posterior distribution and multiple parameters

Tags: bayesian, independence

In this problem I am doing I am trying to model count data with the negative binomial distribution.

$k|(r,p)$ ~ $negBinom(r,p)$

Where we have the following priors:

$ r $ ~ $Exp(2/3)$ and $p$ ~ $Beta(1/2, 1/2)$.

What I want to find is the posterior distribution of $r$ (ie. $r|k$).

What I tried doing to solve this was:

$ f(r|k) \propto f(k|r,p)f(r,p)=f(k|r,p)f(r)f(p)$

But the only way I could justify this was by assuming conditional independence of $r$ and $p$ given the data, but I don't think this can be assumed (perhaps provable though). Is there a better way?

Comment: How did you solve your question? Is it true to say that $f(r|k)\propto f(k|r,p)f(r,p)$?

Answer (score 0):

You have not assumed that $r$ and $p$ are independent given the data which would be $f(r,p|k) = f(r|k)f(p|k)$. You have assumed that $r$ and $p$ are independent in your prior, i.e. $f(r,p) = f(r)f(p)$. It is likely the case that $r$ and $p$ will not be independent in your posterior even when you assume they are independent in your prior.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my problem.

Comment: How did you solve your problem @StackExchangeDisplayName?

Comment: How did they arrive at $f(r|k)\propto f(k|r,p)f(r,p)$? without using that $r$ and $p$ are independent given the data?